# Calculating percentage of points per raster band (elevation, slope, aspect...) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, reclassify

I have a series of rasters expressing environmental variables, for example, elevation. I have used the tool 'add raster values to points' to classify the sites according to the bands (10) I have reclassified the DEM in. I am now looking to calculate the percentage of points for each elevation band, but I am not sure how to proceed. Is there a way to do this in QGIS? It seems like something that should be straightforward but I cannot seem to find a tool to do so.
I am running QGIS3.16.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Statistics by categories](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html?category#statistics-by-categories) tool with your elevation band field as the `Field to calculate statistics on` to get a count of points in each band. Then calculate as a percentage of the total number of point features.

In the `Statistics by category` layer, use the Field Calculator to get the percentage

```py
"count" / sum("count") * 100
```

[image]

*After deleting unnecessary statistics fields* -

[image]